# Failed to find Spark assembly JAR on windows 8.1

Tags: windows, scala, apache-spark

I get this error "Failed to find Spark assembly JAR" when trying to run script spark-shell.cmd from the bin directory. I have downloaded a pre-built version of Spark (1.3.1 for Hadoop 2.6. and later), I have java 1.8 installed and I wish to install this on a Windows 8.1 x64 machine. 
I also have Scala 2.11.6 installed.

Can I get some help as to why this might be happening? 
What additional configuration needs to be made for me to successfully run Spark?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I managed to download the wrong bundle. Sorry for the question